# WSL "No space left on device" error even though hard drive has plenty of space

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

Running into the following error in WSL: "No space left on device"

When trying to install something new. This is despite the fact the hard drive has plenty of space

Answer (score 2):

I completely resolved the issue by following the steps here to check and expand the disk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space

Note that for Ubuntu 18.04, the distro name is "Ubuntu-18.04"